# Considering the open ports, is it more insecure to use Outline then buying a VPN from a provider?

Tags: vpn

OS: Lubuntu When using Outline Manager from Alphabet, it asks to allow incoming TCP connections on ports ranging from 1024 to 65535. Could this be a security flow, more exploitable, than buying a VPN from a third party?

Comment: do you plan running anything other than the *outline* server software on the *Lubuntu* host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time a VPN service allows inbound connections to your device, there could be a risk if you are running services on the exposed ports. So if you are worried about having any services exposed, simply don't enable that option.

Note that any VPN provider could allow this option, or maybe could allow malicious users to probe your device due to a misconfiguration on their end.